# Python reading local time from system (Ubuntu) and getting in a float format

Tags: python

My problem is simple and i am sure you can help. I want python to read the local time from my system (Ubuntu) and transform to a float number e.g. if the time is 10:24:16 i wish to get it as 10.4044. Is there any function in python that can do this?

Comment: Are you asking about getting the time or the conversion, specifically?

Comment: I believe that the first thing python does is to get the local time from the system. Is there any method that can do the conversion immediately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built-in, as that particular format is not exactly a common way to represent time. Still, it's really easy to build your own converter:

```
import time
def current_time_as_float():
    lt = time.localtime()
    return ((lt.tm_sec / 60.) + lt.tm_min / 60.) + lt.tm_hour
```

Comment: Thanks man. I was aware of what you propose, i was just wondering if there was any method ready for use.